# Scrolling text/marquee 

Tags: c#, wpf, text

I wanted to make a scrooling text that goes from right to left.There are some available on internet and used one of those.But soon realized that my text would be of two color and along with the scrolling text i would have to add imagees . this made it complicatedd.Any idea how it can be done.

My idea was to add Label(one color) image then label other color plus image into some stack panel or something and then move it some how.

i am beginner at wpf so i am unable to maky my way out

Comment: Might depend on your hardware but this might be more dificult than it might seem to begin with. You could try experimenting with rendertransform (translate) and some masking and use some storyboard to animate the transform but I guess I had to test this to give really good advice.

Comment: Did you think ever about RichTextBox? If yes why you don't want to use it?

Comment: can it contail images and how can you do scrolling text message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I scroll text in WPF textBlock control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668869/how-do-i-scroll-text-in-wpf-textblock-control)

Comment: @msarchet issue is that i not only need text but images and text in two color as well.....so it may be partial or less than partial duplicate

Comment: @Lagrangian the idea is very similar

Comment: @Lagrangian: What purpose of your question ? Do you want to scroll text and image automatically ? ( For example, scroll text second by second ? )

Comment: Idea was i have a banner and in that banner i have TEXT IMAGE TEXT IMAGE

Answer (score 2):

As i understand from your question, I suggest you to user RichTextBox that you can easily paste image and text. For this purpose, you can do following steps:

- Create your `RichTextBox` and add `FlowDocument` to it ( And also add `Paragraph` to this `FlowDocument` ) :

  **NOTE:** We will use this declared paragraph to add our text and images

  **NOTE:** You must to set `PageWidth` to a large number, because RichTextBox has not option to set TextWrapping ( like a TextWrapping option in TextBox ).

  ```
  <RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextBox1" Height="25">
          <FlowDocument x:Name="FlowDocument1" PageWidth="1000">
                  <Paragraph x:Name="Paragraph1">
                          Your Text Will Be Placed Here
                  </Paragraph>
          </FlowDocument>
  </RichTextBox>
  ```
- You can add your own image to `Paragraph` by following code:

  ```
  Image img = new Image();
  img.Source = YourImageSource;
  img.Width = YourImageWidth;
  Paragraph1.Inlines.Add(img);
  ```
- You can add your own colory text to `Paragraph` with code as follow :

  ```
  string YourText = "ColoryText";
  Paragraph1.Inlines.Add(new Run(YourText) { Foreground = Brushes.Blue });
  ```
- Now, it is enough to declare a `Timer` from System.Timers.Timer and work with Elapsed Event.

Comment: all remains is scrolling using animation?

Comment: I think it is appropriate to use Timer and `RichTextBox1.Selection.Select(,)` method to move cursor from one location to another. Also you can use animation to scrolling.